# Kubuntu 20.04 empty trash sound

Tags: sound, kubuntu

When i delete something from the trash a sound is heard.
How to make the sound no longer heard in **Kubuntu 20.04**?

Comment: In a recent version of Ubuntu (20.04), no such sound is played. I am also using Kubuntu but I do not get such sound.

Comment: The same sound in the Sweeper application. When cleaning the data the same sound is heard.

Comment: Fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04 on a laptop with few applications.

Comment: Try exploring the KDE system settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open ***system setings*** then ***notification***
go to ***applications-configure***
then ***plasma workspace*** and ***configure events***
uncheck *trash-emptied* and *warning message*
[image]