# How do i disable system sound in Kubuntu 22.04.1?

Tags: sound, system

When i empty the trash in Kubuntu it comes a system sound, how can i disable that? In the sound settings i didnt find how to disable that.

Comment: This is a duplicate and has an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262940/kubuntu-20-04-empty-trash-sound

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I turned off the system sound for empty trash now.